# Masking a variable with lat and lon but needed 3d array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, netcdf

what i am trying is masking a value from nc file with numpy array, according to specific location but it gives me 1d array and i can not use this array for plotting here my code.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

file = './sample_data/NSS.AMBX.NK.D08214.S0740.E0931.B5312324.WI.nc'
data = Dataset(file,mode='r')

fcdBT89gHz = np.asarray(data.groups['Data_Fields']['fcdr_brightness_temperature_1'][:])
fcdBT150gHz = np.asarray(data.groups['Data_Fields']['fcdr_brightness_temperature_2'][:])
fcdBT183_1gHz = np.asarray(data.groups['Data_Fields']['fcdr_brightness_temperature_3'][:])
fcdBT183_3gHz = np.asarray(data.groups['Data_Fields']['fcdr_brightness_temperature_4'][:])
fcdBT183_7gHz = np.asarray(data.groups['Data_Fields']['fcdr_brightness_temperature_5'][:])

lats = data.groups['Geolocation_Time_Fields']['latitude'] #Enlem degerleri 
lons = data.groups['Geolocation_Time_Fields']['longitude'] #Boylam degerleri
latlar = np.asarray(lats[:]) # Lati
lonlar = np.asarray(lons[:]) # Long

lo = ma.masked_outside(lonlar,105,110)  
la = ma.masked_outside(latlar,30,35)
merged_coord=~ma.mask_or(la.mask,lo.mask)

h = plt.plot(fcdBT150gHz[merged_coord])
```

The output is like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgJ6S.png) but i need latitudes in x axis like this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTRbW.png)

If you need shape of variables:

```
lo.shape = (2495, 90)
la.shape = (2495, 90)
fcdBT150gHz[merged_coord].shape = (701,)
```

Maybe i did not use true way for masking. If data is needed [here](https://easyupload.io/owoyhp).

Comment: why not create list with pairs `[ (lat1, long1), (lat2, long2), ... ]` - it will be 3D list which you can convert to 3D array. With normla lists you could use `zip()` for this `list(zip(lats, longs))`

Comment: @furas i could not understand. Can you explain what you mean with example ? I can supply anything you need about variable.

Comment: you create 1D array using `fcdBT150gHz[merged_coord]`. If you want 2D then you should use `zip(merged_coord, fcdBT150gHz[merged_coord])` or 3D `zip(merged_coord[0], merged_coord[1], fcdBT150gHz[merged_coord])`. OR you should at least uses `plt.plt( merged_coord[0], fcdBT150gHz[merged_coord] )` and it should use `merged_coord[0]` as `X` and `fcdBT150gHz[merged_coord]` as `Y`. IF you use only once value in `plot()` then it may automatically generate value `0...700` as  `X`

Comment: here some shape of variable, merged_coord[1].shape is 90 but fcdBT150gHz[merged_coord].shape is 701 so they are not  equal when i try plot like you wrote it gives 
<pre> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (90,) and (701,) <code>

and i zip them but i do not how to use this zip variable ?

Comment: as for me you should first create pairs `(lat, long, value_from_fcdBT150gHz)` and later filter it, and later use filtered data to display it.

Comment: frankly, it hard to suggest any solution without data which we could use to run this code .